# Multiple and virtual inheritance C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Full disclaimer, this is homework - not graded, just given to students so we can practice.
I'm asking for help, because we won't get an answer and I just want to know how to solve it.

What I can do is define structures B and C. Their interface has to be "like A's interface, with modifications so it works correctly".
I can't add any new methods. I also can't change anything in struct A.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A;
struct B;
struct C;

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    C c;
}
```

And the desired output is:

```
A::A()
A::A()
B::B()
A::A()
A::A()
B::B()
A::A()
C::C()
```

What I tried to do so far:
First I started like this, just to check things out:

```
struct B : public A {
  B() : A() {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

struct C : public B {
  C() : B() {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};
```

Which gave me:

```
A::A()
B::B()
C::C()
```

So I tried to get first C, then A, then B, then A (desired output from the bottom):

```
struct B : public virtual A {
  B() : A() {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

struct C : public B, public A {
  C() : A(), B() {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};
```

But of course this didn't work. (warning: direct base ‘A’ inaccessible in ‘C’ due to ambiguity)

Adding virtual keyword like below gave me again C, B then A, from the bottom:

```
struct B : public virtual A {
  B() : A() {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

struct C : public virtual A, public B {
  C() : A(), B() {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};
```

If I want to get C, then A I have to do the following (but then there will be no B)

```
struct C : public virtual A {
  C() : A() {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

struct B : public virtual A, public C {
  B() : C(), A() {
      std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};
```

I also have no idea how could I get A::A() twice in a row.

I just want to understand how this should work, but if you still feel like you don't want to help me with a solution, then please leave me some tips.

Comment: Why is this the desired output? It looks like far too much base classes. And I'm not sure if this can be done without `struct D` at the end: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Eva3gAp2Je0Unt00

Comment: fwiw, i read between the lines that you think asking question about homework would be bad per se. That is not really the case imho. It is just that often questions about homework are merely a dump of the assignment without any demonstration of effort from OP, and that is the reason they are often closed and/or downvoted, homework is for you to learn and asking others for a full solution without even attempting something will waste that opportunity, but being about homework alone is no reason for the question being bad in any sense.

Comment: see here for more guidance about homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4117728.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen to be honest, I'm not sure why this is the desired output - I mean, it's just what our teacher provided us with, and what we gotta do is write more code without changing anything he gave us, so we can get that output. It might not make sense, but it's just for practice.
I guess it would be okay to write more structures, but I'm not sure about that. Based on the code with structure D you sent I did this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PhjPatJJLQDHqxx1 which gives the desired output, but I had to use another new struct.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Also, are you sure it can't be done without adding new structs? And is there any way I could try to change the code so I won't get warnings?

Comment: @idclev463035818 ok, thanks, I read it and I get it now :)

Comment: [Cheat](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9570d0335c186477) or [Composition](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d231d5f94d28555) or [tuple](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d92907c8ffbbb44b)

Comment: Avoid to edit question in a way which invalidate posted answers. (as expected output)

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a restriction in the exercise on use of class members:

```
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
    B() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

struct C
    : B
    , A
{
    C() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

    B b;
    A a;
};
```

**UPDATE**

The desired output had changed since my first answer was posted. So previous answer had become wrong. But now you see the point - you can use composition and copy `A a;` to `B` definition and remove `A` inheritance from `C` definition.

Comment: I can't add any new methods - this is what questioner wrote

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, where do you see any new methods?

Comment: You don't need inheritance btw.

Comment: You souldn't inherit both B and A in C, and this doesn't provide the desired output https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y8P89HRLdnCr6IXY

Comment: @anastaciu I think it's my fault because I didn't notice that first line of desired output wasn't shown in the post (due to ```A::A()) and I changed it too late. But I already changed this idea so it gives the desired output.

Comment: @RobinRiddarstjerna, anyway, I gave an answer that renders the desired output without any new structs, I think it fits your requirements, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
struct B : A { //inherit from A
    B() {
        A();
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";       
    }
};

struct C : B { //inherit from B
    C() {
        B();   //anonymous B object
        A();   //anonymous A object
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};
```

[**Running sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5REnI2uRU7tEDlIw)